# reset root pass on xen guest using physical disk

Tags: xen

I've found a few tutorials to reset the password on a xen guest using image files, such as this one:
http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=28779

However I haven't had any luck with examples of modifying this to work with physical disks.

This guest is currently running.  I'd appreciate it if you could start from listing the command to shutdown the guest from the host, all the way through to restarting the xen guest after it's root password has been changed.

also, not sure what this means, but on my local machine "xm" is the command used to interact with xen, not xe like I've seen in most tutorials.

Here is the disk line of the xen config file:

```
disk = [ "phy:/dev/sdb1,xvda,w" ]
```

Thanks,

-Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shutdown the guest using something like

```
xm shutdown <guest>
```

Check so it is shutdown

```
xm top
```

That path hints that it's not an LVM, but a physical disk. This is a job for [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/). Make sure you have it installed. First you check what filesystems you have in that block device:

```
virt-filesystems -a /dev/sdb1
```

Then you mount the root filesystem:

```
guestmount -a /dev/sdb1 -m /dev/<whateverhappenstoberoot> --rw /mnt
```

Change root directory:

```
chroot /mnt/
```

Update your passwords

```
passwd root
```

And then you restore everything

```
logout
unmount /mnt/
xm create /etc/xen/vm/<guest>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
I tried running "yum install '*guestf*'"
but got back:
"No package *guestf* available."
This is on CentOS
Any ideas?

Comment: CentOS Version is 5.5

Answer (score 1):

You can actually get by without installing guestfs tools by doing some manual work instead.

Follow pehrs's advice up to the virt-filesystems command (without including it), then run this:

```
parted -s /dev/sdb1 unit B print
```

This should give you a table listing offsets, like this:

```
Number  Start        End          Size         Type     File system  Flags
 1      32256B       2467583999B  2467551744B  primary  ext2
 2      2467584000B  3981035519B  1513451520B  primary  ext3
 3      3981035520B  3989260799B  8225280B     primary               lba
 4      3989260800B  3997486079B  8225280B     primary
```

The one you need to mount would probably have an ext3 filesystem on it. You can also check for the right number by running `mount` in the guest and looking for the device for the / partition.

Take the number from the 'Start' column minus the B and try this:

```
mkdir /mnt/test
mount -o loop,rw,offset=NUMBER_GOES_HERE /dev/sdb1 /mnt/test
```

Then proceed with `chroot /mnt/test`. All the rest stays the same apart from this change from using /mnt to using /mnt/test - I don't like mounting anything directly on top of /mnt.

Reference: http://www.andremiller.net/content/mounting-hard-disk-image-including-partitions-using-linux

Answer (score 0):

@Eric
The default CentOS repos don't contain the libguestfs tools -- however the epel repository does. In this case, what I'd usually do is set up the epel repository, but then disable it, and only enable it to install specific packages packages.. Like so:

1. rpm -ivh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
2. disable the repository by setting "enabled=0" in each section of /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
3. yum –enablerepo=epel install

That said, I'm not sure exactly which of the packages you will need. http://libguestfs.org/ seems to suggest installing "*guestf*", but that will more than likely install much more than you *really* need.